# Generate code in C

Tags: binding, emacs, elisp

I've got a library in C that I'd like to generate bindings for in Elisp. In Ruby, I'd simply include a header and then use its C API to generate functions and so on. Can I do the same on elisp? `describe-function` often says that a function is in "C source code". How are these generated?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe the functions the emacs describes as being in C-source doe are those defined in the source code of *emacs itself* (i.e. the elisp primitives).

Answer (score 5):

You can check this [Emacs doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Writing-Emacs-Primitives.html) to see how to wrap C function into a DEFUN macro to make it  accessible from Emacs.

Once primitives are defined you need to recompile Emacs, you cannot load them dynamically in the runtime.

Comment: You have to recompile the Emacs. As far as I remember you can load them dynamically in XEmacs.